# Text chat between two different clients

Tags: ajax, flash, web-services, architecture, chat

I am looking for options for project architecture. 
Service - text chat between two clients. An experts or a teachers use an Ajax client, another - a students use a flash (AS3) applications (social networks, AIR apps, Android AIR apps, etc).

How best to organize a chat between the two? The server side can use PHP and mySQL.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP.MySQL and AJAX aren't for chats, Try using Node.JS and Socket.IO

Comment: Thanx. I`ll see it. But student`s client must be Flash.

Comment: Yeah, that's possible with Flash.